# Getting all Keys associated with the max value in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD, and i want to find all Keys which have the max values. 
So if i have

```
( ((A), 5), ((B), 4), ((C), 5)) )
```

then i want to return

```
( ((A), 5), ((C), 5)) )
```

Edit; MaxBy only gives out one key, so i dont think that will work.

I have tried

```
newRDD = oldRDD.sortBy(._2, false).filter{._2 == _.first}¨
```

and

```
newRDD = oldRDD.filter{_._2 == _.maxBy}
```

Where i know _.first and _.MaxBy wont work, but are supposed to get the maxValue from the oldRDD. My problem in every solution i try is that i cant accsess the maxValue inside a filter. I also belive the 2nd "solution" i tried is much quicker than the first since sortBy is not really necessary.

Comment: Have you tried using `maxBy`?

Comment: In general we expect _I want to_ to be followed with _I tried_ -  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: @user6910411 Every question not enclosed in a `want { ... } try { ... } catch { ... }`-block is a syntax error? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer. The logic is pretty simple:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 5), ("b", 4), ("c", 5)))

// first get maximum value
val maxVal = rdd.values.max

//  now filter to those elements with value==max value
val rddMax = rdd.filter { case (_, v) => v == maxVal }
rddMax.take(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with spark/RDD. In plain Scala, I would do:

```
scala> val max = ds.maxBy (_._2)._2
max: Int = 5

scala> ds.filter (_._2 == max)
res207: List[(String, Int)] = List((A,5), (C,5))
```

Setup was:

```
scala> val (a, b, c) = ("A", "B", "C")
a: String = A
b: String = B
c: String = C

scala> val ds = List ( ((a), 5), ((b), 4), ((c), 5))
ds: List[(String, Int)] = List((A,5), (B,4), (C,5))
```